# ANDROID: Is there is free 3rd party media player for streaming MPEG4 video?

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, media-player, mpeg-4

The native Media Player coming with the android SDK doesnt play most of the MPEG4 format video files. Is there an alternate 3rd party media players that I can use? If yes how can i use then? Will it be a jar that I can add to my lib directory or shd redirect the users to Android Market and ask them to install the FREE app ? which is the best approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Robert   -- > Why is this question closed? Please give a reason

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq]

Comment: My question was which media player JAVA CLASS to use that can be integrated into android app for streaming MPEG4 videos. I had issues with the android native MediaPlayer.java.

Comment: theoretically, you can compile VLC in android NDK. it seems hard to implement, but if you make serious application, this is the best solution

Comment: What is for mpeg4 streaming ? To play the streaming, or make streaming from your android device ? We can use MediaPlay to play mp4 files on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vitamio](http://vov.io/vitamio/) is a library you can use and supports a range of formats. E.g.
divx/xvid
wmv
flv
ts
rmvb
mkv
mov
m4v
avi
mp4
3gp

Answer (score 0):

We use the `HLS Android` player library from `Nexstreaming`.

It works pretty well in all android devices. For us, it was too complicated to use `FFMPEG` and impossible to forecast the future/roadmap of the code so, we gave up on that path.